# Let $P(x, y)$ be the predicate x $\ge$ y for x $\in \mathbb{N}$ and y $\in \mathbb{N}$. Find the truth value of the following statements.

Tags: logic

What do you observe?

$$
a) \;\;\;\;\;
\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall y \in \mathbb{N}: P(x, y), \;\;\;\;\; \forall y \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall x \in \mathbb{N}: P(x, y) 
$$

$$
\\
b) \;\;\;\;\;
\forall x \in \mathbb{N} \; \exists y \in \mathbb{N}: P(x, y), \;\;\;\;\; \exists y \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall x \in \mathbb{N}: P(x, y)
$$

$$
\\
c) \;\;\;\;\;
\exists x \in \mathbb{N} \; \forall y \in \mathbb{N}: P(x, y), \;\;\;\;\; \forall y \in \mathbb{N} \; \exists x \in \mathbb{N}: P(x, y)
$$

$$
\\
d) \;\;\;\;\;
\exists x \in \mathbb{N} \; \exists y \in \mathbb{N}: P(x, y), \;\;\;\;\; \exists y \in \mathbb{N} \; \exists x \in \mathbb{N}: P(x, y)
$$

Answer (score 0):

---

**Solution:**
(a) **false**, let x = 1, then e.g. for y = 2 we have 1 < 2. Also **false**, if y = 2, then e.g. for x = 1, we have 1 < 2.
(b) **true**, let x, be any natural number, then we have x $\ge$ x, hence if we choose y = x, we have x $\ge$ y.
(c) **false**, assume there is such a number x. We set y to be the natural number x + 1, thus we get x $\ge$ x + 1, which is a contradiction.
**true**, let y be any natural number, and let x be the natural number y + 1. We then have y + 1 $\ge$ y, which is a tautology.
(d) **true**, let x = 5, y = 2, then 5 $\ge$ 2.
**true**, let y = 2, x = 5, then 5 $\ge$ 2.

We may observe: changing the order of quantification of variables does not seem to matter, if the quantors are the same, i.e. both universal quantors $\forall$ or both existential quantors $\exists$. Changing the order of quantification might matter, if the quantors are different.